# Problems with using .preventDefault in my project

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to build a test run for a  basic project im working on.

I want the user to use the two forms to enter their day and month of birth and return their star sign.
It seemed to be working until I tried using .preventDefault. It still seems to be trying to lad another page and I cant figure out where i went wrong.

Here is the code and feel free to critique me on any of it, Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Starsign Calc.</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="get">
      <h3>Enter Your Month and Day of Birth</h3>
      <select name="usermonth" id="usermonth">
        <option value="january">January</option>
        <option value="febuary">Febuary</option>
        <option value="march">March</option>
        <option value="april">April</option>
      </select>
      <input name="userday" id="userday" type="number" min="1" max="31" value="1" />
      <input id="change-placeholder" type="submit" />
    </form>
    <hr />
    <h1>You are a ???????</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript">
          document.getElementById('change-placeholder').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            let birthMonth = document.getElementById('usermonth').value;
            let birthDay = document.getElementById('userday').value;

            //is user a Pisces?
            if (birthMonth === 'febuary' && birthDay >= 19 && birthDay <= 28) {
            document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = "You are a Pisces";
            } else if (userMonth === 'march' && userDay <= 20) {
            document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = "You are a Pisces";

      }
          };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: listen to the form submit event instead - or don't use a form  - but that doesn't help if the code is invalid, and uses variables that are not declared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not closed `)` in your script at the end after `}`. That's the first syntax error, which needs to be corrected.

Clicking on the button gives me this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: userMonth is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:12:18)
```

So you need to correctly define what's happening. So change all `user*` to `birth*` in the `else` part:

```
if (birthMonth === "febuary" && birthDay >= 19 && birthDay <= 28) {
  document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "You are a Pisces";
} else if (birthMonth === "march" && birthDay <= 20) {
  document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "You are a Pisces";
}
```

And finally, you need a final `else` statement if none matches:

```
if (birthMonth === "febuary" && birthDay >= 19 && birthDay <= 28) {
  document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "You are a Pisces";
} else if (birthMonth === "march" && birthDay <= 20) {
  document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "You are a Pisces";
} else {
  document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "I am not sure...";
}
```

So you can see it working.

Complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Starsign Calc.</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="get">
      <h3>Enter Your Month and Day of Birth</h3>
      <select name="usermonth" id="usermonth">
        <option value="january">January</option>
        <option value="febuary">Febuary</option>
        <option value="march">March</option>
        <option value="april">April</option>
      </select>
      <input name="userday" id="userday" type="number" min="1" max="31" value="1" />
      <input id="change-placeholder" type="submit" />
    </form>
    <hr />
    <h1>You are a ???????</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document
        .getElementById("change-placeholder")
        .addEventListener("click", function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          let birthMonth = document.getElementById("usermonth").value;
          let birthDay = document.getElementById("userday").value;

          //is user a Pisces?
          if (birthMonth === "febuary" && birthDay >= 19 && birthDay <= 28) {
            document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "You are a Pisces";
          } else if (birthMonth === "march" && birthDay <= 20) {
            document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "You are a Pisces";
          } else {
            document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "I am not sure...";
          }
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Working Snippet: [JSBin](https://output.jsbin.com/zupufezabe/1)**

**Alternate Approach**

You may listen to the `form`'s `onSubmit` or `submit` event instead of the `input:submit`'s `click` event.